# How to configure maven checkstyle plugin to print suppressions output

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I would like the maven checkstyle plugin to print the suppressions that need to be added to the suppressions file to make the checkstyle pass.

I think there's a flag (-g) to do this in the checkstyle CLI, but not sure how to do this in the plugin.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-382# filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven checkstyle doesn't support that option right now.

I would request it on their issue tracker at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MCHECKSTYLE/issues/ .

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-382# filed.